# Convert image into useable byte array in C?

Tags: c++, c, image, arrays, byte

Does anyone know how to open an image, specifically a jpg, to a byte array in C or C++? Any form of help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of byte array? Byte array of pixel colors?

Comment: What's the point?  An image is only interesting when it paints pixels somewhere.  Bytes are boring.  Use FileStream + byte[(int)fs.Length], if you have to.

Answer (score 2):

The [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-core.php) library can do this too, although often it provides enough image manipulation functions that you can do many things without needing to convert the image to a byte array and handle it yourself.

Comment: From the introduction: "recommended for wizard-level programmers only" o_O

Comment: @DerMike: That's just to make beginners feel better about themselves, it's really not that hard :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [DevIL Image Library](http://openil.sourceforge.net/)  I've only used it in relation to OpenGL related things, but it also functions as just a plain image loading library.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the source code for wxImage in the [wxWidgets GUI Framework](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wximage.html#wximage).  You will most likely be interested in the *nix distribution.

Another alternative is the GNU Jpeg library.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it using GDIPlus [Bitmap.LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method defined in the header GdiPlusBitmap.h:

```
    Gdiplus::BitmapData bitmapData;
    Gdiplus::Rect rect(0, 0, bitmap.GetWidth(), bitmap.GetHeight());

    //get the bitmap data
    if(Gdiplus::Ok == bitmap.LockBits(
                        &rect, //A rectangle structure that specifies the portion of the Bitmap to lock.
                        Gdiplus::ImageLockModeRead | Gdiplus::ImageLockModeWrite, //ImageLockMode values that specifies the access level (read/write) for the Bitmap.            
                        bitmap.GetPixelFormat(),// PixelFormat values that specifies the data format of the Bitmap.
                        &bitmapData //BitmapData that will contain the information about the lock operation.
                        ))
    {
         //get the lenght of the bitmap data in bytes
         int len = bitmapData.Height * std::abs(bitmapData.Stride);

         BYTE* buffer = new BYTE[len];
         memcpy(bitmapData.Scan0, buffer, len);//copy it to an array of BYTEs

         //... 

         //cleanup
         pBitmapImageRot.UnlockBits(&bitmapData);       
         delete []buffer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have my students use [netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/) to represent images because it comes with a handy C library, but you can also put images into text form, create them by hand, and so on.  The nice thing here is that you can convert all sorts of images, not just JPEGs, into PBM format, using command-line tools the Unix way.  The `djpeg` tool is available a number of places including the [JPEG Club](http://jpegclub.org/).  Students with relatively little experience can write some fairly sophisticated programs using this format.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV can also do this.

http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/index.html

search for: "Accessing image elements"